# Pycharm failing to import Pandas

Tags: pandas, pycharm, importerror

I'm new to Python and Pycharm. I installed the pandas via the Project Interpreter however when I coded "

import pandas as pd
It is greyed out and prompts a warning as "this inspection detects names that should resolve but don't...."

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Gary
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yspYi.png)

Comment: read the error message again. it's a warning saying that you have an import but don't use it. use it and it will go away.

Comment: Thanks! it's resolved!